# Remote Solidity Compiler vs LocalNodeModule

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I was writing Solidity contract like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Contract {}
```

However, I received this error

```
"Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol" not found: File import callback not supported"
```

For context, I am using latest Solidity extension v0.0.139 and 0.8.15 for global compiler version (Remote). If I change compiler to LocalNodeModule, I will have issue with `pragma solidity ^0.8.13` statement. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

did you run:

npm install @openzeppelin/contracts ??

I think this should fix the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So far this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

First, verify if the file Ownable.sol is installed by checking if it exists under node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/

if it does not exist then launch the command: npm install @openzeppelin/contracts
if it does exist, then it could be a problem with your editor try to close and re-open your file ( happened to me once )